# How to direct the response from a call to an external API back to the requesting web server in a load balanced (nginx) environment?

Tags: php, api, nginx, load-balancing

I have some PHP web servers that are load balanced by nginx.

The web servers need to make requests to an external API (that I don't have control of) and then receive a response.

1) What ways are there of ensuring the response is returned to the correct (requesting) web server?

2) What are the pros and cons of each?

Thanks!

*Update (2011-12-05 12:38pm):*

Some more background information as to what's trying to be achieved.

We run a client facing application that has a number of php web servers that are balanced using nginx.  Client could be directed to any of those web servers.

```
               nginx
                 |
 --------------------------------
        |        |        |  
      web1      web2     web3
```

Sometimes we need to fetch data from an external (third party API) which we then return back to the client. The request to that data could have originated from any of the web servers (depending on which the client was originally directed to by nginx). We need to ensure that the data from the API gets returned back to the requesting web server to be displayed to the client.

Comment: The responses will always be returned directly to the requesting web server, won't they? Surely the requesting web server opens a direct TCP stream to the remote API, which means the response will be returned using that same TCP stream - and will always come back to the right place. Unless you have some kind of proxy for the API in your server set up - which would sort of make the load balancing pointless, as you have given yourself a single point of failure. Even then, I would have thought this still would not be a problem, unless the proxy is designed in a *very* odd way.

Comment: @DaveRandom "Surely the requesting web server opens a direct TCP stream to the remote API" - I don't think you are right. From 192.168.1.2 you make a request through nginx public ip xx.yy.zz.pp and the API response gets back to the public ip where it might get redirected to 192.168.1.3. ip_hash directive prevents that.

Comment: @narcisradu but is it not just NATed? This sounds like the sort of thing that should be handled at layer 3 (of the TCP/IP model) to me, adding something at layer 4 to do this adds much complication and processing overhead. Unless there is something I'm missing...

Comment: @DaveRandom The web servers don't have public facing IP addresses, all requests must go through the reverse proxy (nginx server) before reaching the external API.

Comment: Ok no worries, I'll just shut up and butt out :-D (although the last thing I will say is that this question *might* be better on http://www.serverfault.com/, but that is debatable)

Answer (score 1):

You may use: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#ip_hash

The downside: sometimes one of the servers might get very busy but you need to benchmark the solution and find where the problem might be.

Comment: We already use ip_hash so that clients get directed to the same web server each time.

This does not help when our servers need to fetch data from an external API however. The API provider's IP might be directed to the same web server each time but any of our web servers could have made that request initially. e.g. all API returns might get directed to web1 based on the API provider's IP being the same, but the request might have come from web1, web2 or web3

Comment: now I understand! You don't know what web-server initiated the API call, so how can you redirect the API return to the proper one without knowing which one is actually? One dirty solution: use different upstreams but I need to think about how to actually implement it.

Comment: can you please explain why do you need the API answer to be redirected to the same backend server? I assume you may actually receive the answer on any other server and fetch the response internal. But this is more an architecture issue and it's hard to provide a solution without actually knowing what happens in your application.